# How to free QByteArray created with fromRawData()

Tags: c++, qt, memory-management

The docs state [the following](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qbytearray.html#fromRawData):

> QByteArray does not take ownership of data, so the QByteArray
>   destructor will never delete the raw data, even when the last
>   QByteArray referring to data is destroyed.

With that in mind, how does one free a `QByteArray` created in this way?

Conceptually - I'd guess calling `free()` on the pointer via `data()` or `constData()`, but I'm really not sure... here's a code sample illustrating the use case:

```
void doTest() {
    QByteArray qba = partOne();
    partTwo(qba);
    finished(qba);
}

QByteArray partOne() {

    char *dataPtr = (char *)malloc(64);
    //do some stuff to dataPtr

    QByteArray qba = QByteArray::fromRawData(dataPtr, 64);
    //do some stuff to qba
    return qba;
}

void partTwo(QByteArray qba) {
    //do more stuff to qba
}

void finished(QByteArray qba) {
    //this?
    free((void *)qba.constData());
}
```

Comment: The very prominent example on that page starts with `static const char mydata[] = {`. How would you free *that*?

Comment: This question is deficient without a clear statement as to why do you allocate the memory via `malloc` to begin with. In C++ code it'd be an antipattern. You are aware of `QByteArray::data()` method as a way to interoperate with code that needs a raw pointer, right?

Comment: Consider a case where we don't allocate the memory, but rather get a pointer to allocated memory from one library, and need to pass that data as a QByteArray to another- preferably without copying.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> how does one free a `QByteArray` created in this way?

It's simple - one doesn't. The byte array doesn't take ownership of the data, so you don't "free it" from the byte array.

If there is a necessity to free the data, that responsibility should fall to the code that allocated the data. After you are done with the byte array and there exist no further references to it.

The data may or may not be "free-able", thus you should not try to free it from the byte array. Whatever mechanism allocated the data should handle its deallocation.

```
memory allocation
    byte array construction
        byte array usage  
    byte array destruciton
memory deallocation
```

Edit: Keep in mind that with [COW](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/implicit-sharing.html) there is a big difference between "do stuff to" and "do stuff with" as in you reading or writing, because the moment you write, COW kicks in, the underlying data will be copied and the changes will be applied to it rather than the original data. Naturally, this only happens if more than one byte array instances implicitly share the data, as for example it would be in `partTwo()`. If you don't want this to happen, pass by reference rather than by copy. Obviously, if COW kicks in, it would be a problem if you free the memory from `data()`, because you will free the new memory that was allocated by the byte array, and your original allocation would turn into a memory leak. Thus the solution below provisions against that possibility.

```
void doTest() {
    char *dataPtr = (char *)malloc(64);
    //do some stuff to dataPtr
    {
        QByteArray qba = partOne(dataPtr);
        partTwo(qba);
    } // qba dies here
    free(dataPtr);
}  

QByteArray partOne(char *dataPtr) {
    QByteArray qba = QByteArray::fromRawData(dataPtr, 64);
    //do some stuff to qba
    return qba;
}

void partTwo(QByteArray qba) {
    //do more stuff to qba
}
```

Comment: Let's assume that steps 1-3 (memory allocation -> construction -> some usage) are happening in one function, and the rest of the steps are happening elsewhere (more usage -> destruction -> deallocation).

With that in mind, how should that "elsewhere" function deal with deallocation?

Comment: Maybe it wasn't too illustrative to say "the code that allocated", more the the conceptual program unit. If you don't pass the byte array to any other places, it will "die" as it goes out of scope in the end of that one function, so you can deallocate the data just before the function returns, this would in theory reverse the last two steps, but it will be ok as long as nobody uses the array anymore. Or you can use a smart pointer to manage the memory automatically, then you can have the sequence as outlined above.

Comment: If you post additional information what exactly you are doing with the byte array I can be more precise.

Comment: @davidkomer If steps 1-3 happen in one function, and then you pass out a `QByteArray` out of that function yet you also need to manage the lifetime of some other object that `QByteArray` happens to depend on, your design is broken. Either use a `QByteArray` instead of the raw pointer to start with, or don't use a `QByteArray` at all, and use a custom class instead.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for you to manage the memory manually at all:

```
QByteArray partOne() {
  QByteArray qba(64, Qt::Uninitialized);
  auto dataPtr = qba();
  // use dataPtr
  // do some stuff to qba
  return qba;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`fromRawData` doesn't take ownership, so memory should be freed by object which owns data you need to free.

> Conceptually - I'd guess calling free() on the pointer via .data() or .constData(), but I'm really not sure...

It's incorrect as you cannot guarantee that `QByteArray` doesn't own the data. E.g. if you modify the content of the `QByteArray` the deep copy will be created and this copy will be freed by `QByteArray` destructor:

> A subsequent attempt to modify the contents of the returned QByteArray or any copy made from it will cause it to create a deep copy of the data array before doing the modification. This ensures that the raw data array itself will never be modified by QByteArray.